# How can i get domain name in Nestjs?

Tags: nestjs

Now, i want to get domain name. I don't want hardcode for path return 
eg: https://mydomain/url-img. My purpose is when i develop in local enviroment, I can return url which like that http://localhost:3000/url-img.

Answer (score 4):

Your best solution would be to use the `dotenv` package (or use docker-compose instead) and in your `.env` file have something like

```sh
DOMAIN="http://localhost:3000"
```

and set it differently in prod. Then in your code you just access it with `process.env.DOMAIN` and append the `/url-img` to the domain for the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `x-forwarded-proto` from the headers and then construct it with a string iterator to form your full domain.

Here is a snippet from my code.

```
  import { Request} from '@nestjs/common';
  import { Request as ExpressRequest } from 'express';

  ...

  @ApiExcludeEndpoint()
  @Get(['api', 'docs', 'playground'])
  @Render('index.hbs')
  docs(@Request() request?: ExpressRequest) {
    const hour = new Date().getHours();
    return {
      schema_url: `${request.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] ?? request.protocol}://${request.headers.host}/swagger-json`,
      theme: hour < 6 && hour > 19 ? 'dark' : 'light'
    }
  }
```